# how to solve "no module named networkx" Error?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mininet, openflow, topology, pox

i am trying to run a python code as pox controller using below command :

```
./pox.py openflow.discovery CloudNetController
```

but always i get this error:

```
could not import module : CloudNetController
```

please help how can i solve this error.

Comment: install networkx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](https://github.com/dedousis/CloudnetController/blob/master/CloudNetController.py) controller?

this controller imports :

`import networkx as nx`

Hence you should

> pip install networkx